# Execute PHP on server with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, server, execute

Hi I am trying to get ajax to execute code on the server and return the result:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post('includes/gallery/gallery.php', function(data){
            $('#galleryTab').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>

class Main{
public static function generateGallery(){
    $path = 'includes/gallery/';
    $results = glob($path . '*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    $dirCount = 0;
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $resultBaseName = basename($result);
        if ($resultBaseName === '.' or $resultBaseName === '..') continue;
        echo '<h2>'.$resultBaseName.'</h2>';
        if (is_dir($path . '/' . $resultBaseName)) {
            $dir = $path.$resultBaseName.'/';
            $images = glob($dir."*.jpg");
            $imageCount = 0;
            foreach($images as $image) {
                echo '<div class="galleryImage" id="openImage'.$imageCount.$dirCount.'"><img src="'.$image.'" /></div>';
                $imageCount++;
            }
        }
        echo '<br />';
        $dirCount++;
    }
}
}
```

It is not executing the PHP on the server, please help

Comment: Have you checked php is installed in your server? Try test file with phpinfo() and upload it to server.

Comment: It returns PHP Version 5.5.11. I can run any php file when running it directly, but requesting it with Ajax only return html, it does not execute the php.

Comment: Okay try simple file with ajax for testing say mail() to test if it's having XMLHttprequest issue.

Comment: try using the network tab in the developer console in chrome or firefox, to see what the ajax requests are sending & returning

Comment: mail() is also not working, it seems that it skips anything within the <?php ?> tags

Comment: contact hosting support team of this issue

Comment: I am hosting locally for testing, I will try uploading the site and see

Comment: It shows up in the console under XHR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is not enough. You should Return your result from the function as an array and encode it with json_encode php function or in any other interchange formats. see the below statement.

```
            $returnResult = json_encode($array);
```

Then use $.ajax({}) jquery method in your client side. See the example below.

```
 $.ajax({

      url : url , // <-your url here
      method : post or get ,
      data : { field: value }, //provide the values you are passing  <-
      dataType: json or html,  //data interchange format
      success : function(data){

        console.log(data.value);

       }

      });
```

see jquery $.ajax({}) documentation here [Jquery documentation link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Hi Jijo, I have successfully converted the data to an array and encoded it with json, the output looks right. unfortunately nothing is being logged to the console........

Comment: Your answer is leading me to the conclusion, I have incorrectly assigned the $path for the generateGallery() function......when I used the json method you described above it displayed in the console that the string is empty which I wanted to convert to an array.......I then went and looked at the directories......they were wrong.........I feel so dumb now, thank you for your help Jijo

Answer (score 1):

You defined your class and its method there, but you are not calling it based on the code you show us. Call the "generateGallery" method from "main" class, and it should work.

Comment: I have it in the original code, apologies for not posting it together with the code, I am calling it with: "Main::generateGallery();"......

I have included this outside of the php tags: <h1>TEST</h1>.

That shows up, but everything inside the php tags, is not executing.....